# How to add field to a DE using SSJS in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I have a DE called "My Demo DE" and the customer key for it is "`demoDE`".

Now i want to add a new field to this existing DE.It my SSJS code is not adding the Field to the DE.

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1");
var de = DataExtension.Init('My Demo DE');

var newField = {
  Name : "NewFieldV2",
  CustomerKey : "demoDE",
  FieldType : "Number",
  IsRequired: true,
  DefaultValue: "100"
};
var status = de.Fields.Add(newField);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataExtension.Init should have the CustomerKey instead of DE name.

Hence, based on your previous question that I answered, it must be:

```
var de = DataExtension.Init('demoDE');
```